# find part between string and change it

Tags: php

I know how to find a (part of a) string and change that, but the problem is, the part I have to change is variable in length and in characters.

example

```
$string = "bla1bla2bla3textbla4bla5";
```

normaly I should explode to filter out text, but because "bla3" is different to "bla4", I have no idea how to explode or find "text", however it's always between "bla3" and "bla4", but "text" is variable aswel as bla1, 2 and 5.
after I find "text" I need to replace it by an other text.

Perhaps I can find this on google, but the problem is, I have no clue how to discribe it.

Comment: Try using `regular expressions` for php would be a function called `preg_replace`

Comment: Can you edit with 3 or 4 examples of different scenarios? We can then work out a suitable regex.

Comment: Why use a regex when you can use `str_replace`?

Answer (score 0):

**Using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):**

```
$parts = explode('text',$string); //splits it into two parts, removing `text`
$string = $parts[0] .'replacement'. $parts[1]; //glue the parts together with replacement
```

**Using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):**

```
$string = str_replace('text','replacement');
```

And as for describing your problem: I'd try googling something like `php replace substring`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_split() for this. I can't remember the exact regex for this, but it should be something like:

```
$text = preg_split("/[0-9]*/", "bla1bla2bla3textbla4bla5");
```

Comment: For the especifi problem  the expression would be `/(bla)(3|4)/`

Answer (score 0):

ok, some examples.

```
$string1 = "bla1bla2bla3textbla4bla5";
```

find "text" in $string and replace it by "example"

output:

```
$string1 = "bla1bla2bla3examplebla4bla5";
```

other example

```
$string2 = "I bla3don'tbla4 know how to do it"
```

find "don't" in $string and replace it by "example"

output:

```
$string2 = "I bla3examplebla4 know how to do it"
```

other example

```
$string3 = "textbla3textbla4text"
```

find "text" but only the one between bla3 and bla4 and replace it by "example"

output shoud be something like

```
$string3 = "textbla3examplebla4text"
```

hope this makes it more clear.
so the part of bla3 and bla 4 stay the same, but anything else can change.